# I want to update the parent according to the change of the child to react native

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

i have a problem updating the parent state. indeed I want to change the edge of an edge after the user has clicked and chosen his level of performance in sport. after having chosen its level of performance, it is then that the selected sport takes a blue border.
please i need help

**Sport.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Modal,
  Alert,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableHighlight,
  ScrollView,
} from "react-native";

import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { ProgressBar, Colors } from "react-native-paper";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import SportItem from "../../Components/SportItem";
import HeadCSearch from "../../Components/HeadCSearch";
import SearchTitle from "../../Components/SearchTitle";
import ModalPicker from "./ModalPicker";

export default function Sport() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [chooseData, setchooseData] = useState("0%");
  const [sports, setSports] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      urlIcon: "ios-football",
      name: "Football",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      urlIcon: "hand-left-sharp",
      name: "Handball",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      urlIcon: "ios-basketball",
      name: "Basketball",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      urlIcon: "ios-car-sport",
      name: "Course",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      urlIcon: "ios-baseball",
      name: "BaseBall",
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      urlIcon: "ios-tennisball",
      name: "Tennis",
    },
    /* {
      id: 7,
      urlIcon:
        "https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/50/000000/basketball-net.png",
      name: "Basketball",
    }, */
  ]);

  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const changeModalVisibility = (bool, id) => {
    setModalOpen(bool);
    sports.map((sport) => {
      if (id === sport.id) {
        const newState = !toggle;
        setToggle(newState);
      }
    });
  };
  const setData = (option) => {
    setchooseData(option);
  };

  const OPTIONS = ["Débutant", "Moyen", "Intermédiaire", "Expert"];

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    "Gilroy-ExtraBold": require("../../assets/fonts/Gilroy-ExtraBold.otf"),
    "Gilroy-Light": require("../../assets/fonts/Gilroy-Light.otf"),
  });
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {
    const borderColorValue = toggle ? "#49B5F2" : "white";
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.infoCont}>
        <ProgressBar
          style={{ marginTop: 35, borderRadius: 10 }}
          progress={1}
          color="#49B5F2"
        />
        <View style={styles.containWhite}>
          <SearchTitle
            styl={styles.whiteText}
            partenaire={"Choississez vos Sports Favoris"}
          />

          {/* <Modal visible={modalOpen} animationType="slide" transparent={true}>
                    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                        <Text>Salut toi</Text>
                    </View>
                </Modal>  */}

          <Modal
            animationType="slide"
            transparent={true}
            visible={modalOpen}
            onRequestClose={() => {
              changeModalVisibility(false);
            }}
          >
            <ModalPicker
              sports={sports}
              OPTIONS={OPTIONS}
              setData={setData}
              changeModalVisibility={changeModalVisibility}
            />
          </Modal>

          <ScrollView
            contentContainerStyle={{
              backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF",
              flexWrap: "wrap",
              flexDirection: "row",
              /* borderColor: "yellow",
              borderWidth: 3,
              borderStyle: "solid", */
            }}
          >
            {sports.map((sport) => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => {
                  changeModalVisibility(true, sport.id);
                }}
                style={{
                  alignItems: "center",
                  display: "flex",
                  flexDirection: "row",
                  bottom: 10,
                  width: 150,
                  height: 50,
                  margin: 10,
                  backgroundColor: "#E4E9DD",
                  borderColor: borderColorValue,
                  borderWidth: 1,
                  borderRadius: 5,
                }}
                key={sport.id}
              >
                <View
                  style={{
                    alignItems: "center",
                    display: "flex",
                    flexDirection: "row",
                  }}
                >
                  <Ionicons
                    style={{ left: 8, top: 0 }}
                    name={sport.urlIcon}
                    size={20}
                    color="black"
                  />
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontFamily: "Gilroy-Light",
                      fontWeight: "bold",
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: "#000000",
                      left: 15,
                    }}
                  >
                    {sport.name}
                  </Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.rate}>
                  <Text style={styles.rateText}>{chooseData}</Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Search")}
          style={styles.textinputcont}
        >
          <Text style={styles.textR}>Continuer</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

**ModalPicker.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Text,
} from "react-native";
import { Fontisto } from "@expo/vector-icons";

import SearchTitle from "../../Components/SearchTitle";
export default function ModalPicker(props) {
  const WIDTH = Dimensions.get("window").width;
  const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get("window").height;

  const onPressItem = (option) => {
    props.changeModalVisibility(false);
    props.setData(option);
  };

  const option = props.OPTIONS.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.option}
        key={index}
        onPress={() => onPressItem(item)}
      >
        <Text
          style={[
            styles.textStyle,
            {
              width: 100,
              height: 40,
              backgroundColor: "#F7F7F7",
              borderRadius: 4,
              /* borderColor: "#49B5F2",
              borderWidth: 1,
              borderStyle: "solid", */
              color: "black",
              flexDirection: "row",
              margin: 2,
              top: 5,
              flex: 1,
              //top: 15,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            },
          ]}
        >
          {item}
        </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  });

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      onPress={() => props.changeModalVisibility(false)}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View style={styles.centeredView}>
        <View
          style={[styles.modalView, { width: WIDTH - 85, height: HEIGHT / 3 }]}
        >
          <SearchTitle
            styl={[styles.whiteText, { top: -50 }]}
            partenaire={"Votre Niveau"}
          />
          <Text style={[styles.modalText, styles.centeredView, { top: -50 }]}>
            {option}
          </Text>

          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              ...styles.openButton,
              top: -30,
              left: 30,
            }}
            onPress={() => {
              console.log("remove border color");
            }}
          >
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Retirez des favoris {"     "} </Text>

            <Fontisto
              style={{ position: "absolute", right: 0, top: 10 }}
              name="minus-a"
              size={20}
              color="black"
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: You are already using props to update parent state. Why don't you use the same logic ?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: see my repo here please https://github.com/Francis6-precisio/Fitness.git

Comment: @MihaiT T it didn't work very well

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the styles dynamically inserted into your code.
and having an event raised from the child component and handled in the parent component, the following code can help to understand that

```
 class Parent extends React.Component {
        constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = {
            backgroundColor: 'yellow'
        }
    }

    onChangeStyle(backgroundColor) {
        this.setState({
            backgroundColor: backgroundColor
        })
    }

    render() {
        return <div style={{backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor, padding: 10}}>
            <Child onChangeParentStyle={this.onChangeStyle.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    onClick() {
        this.props.onChangeParentStyle('red');
    }
    render() {
        return <span onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)} style={{background: 'white', cursor: 'pointer'}}>
            Change parent style
        </span>
    }
}

React.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: bind ? Class ? this is sooo 2017 :)

Comment: it's a valid code, functional components are also right

Comment: well the op is using apples. but you give him bananas. It's fruit but still, not the same and especially, not really helpful. THe syntax for functional components + hooks for setting state is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass from parent to child callback function, and then call it in the child.

```
const initState = {
  show: false
}
const Parent = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ ...initState })
  const updateState = (childState) => {
      setState({
          show: !state.show
      });
  }
  return (
      <Child {...{ updateState }} />
  );
}

const Child = (props) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({})
  const handleClick = () => {
      // You can also pass data to parent
      props.updateState(state);
  }
  return (
      <Button onClick={handleClick}>Click Me</Button>
  );
}
```