# TouchableOpacity's onPress is not working

Tags: react-native, onpress

Task.js

```
export const Task = ({ addTask }) => {
  const [focusItem, setFocusItem] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>What would you like to focus on?</Text>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          maxLength={50}
          value={focusItem}
          onSubmitEditing={()=>({ nativeEvent: { text } }) => setFocusItem(text)}
        />
        <RoundedButton
          style={styles.addSubject}
          size={50}
          title="+"
          onPress={()=>addTask(focusItem)}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import {Task} from './src/features/task/Task'

export default function App() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState(null);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
     
        {
          task ? 
          (<Text></Text>):
          (<Task addTask = {setTask}/>)
        }
        <Text>{task}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#425670',
  },
});
```

I have tried to send the data from Task to App component by setting the value from Task. But onPress is not working.
I could see the text has been set successfully while executing the onSubmitEditing, but the onPress is doing nothing. Please help me fix this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: there is no `TouchableOpacity` in your given code

Answer (score 1):

You need to change this

```
onSubmitEditing={()=>({ nativeEvent: { text } }) => setFocusItem(text)}
```

to

```
onSubmitEditing={({ nativeEvent: { text } }) => setFocusItem(text)}
```

You could also refer [I want to update the parent according to the change of the child to react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68957825/i-want-to-update-the-parent-according-to-the-change-of-the-child-to-react-native/68961229#68961229)

Comment: Actually the first change isn't necessary as `setTask` is a reference to the setter of the `useState` hook.

Comment: Yes, you are right. A have modified my answer.